# Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: node.js

I am working between the oracle (instantclient) and Nodejs app. it works on the dev (local machines - windows flavor). When I try to deploy the same app in PCF foundation. it is not getting deployed and throws the following error

> [ERR] DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help

i followed below steps:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/oracle/instantclient:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}`
export OCI_LIB_DIR=$HOME/oracle/instantclient
export OCI_INC_DIR=$HOME/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include`
my_app/
|---- index.js
  |---- package.json
  |---- node_modules/
  |---- oracle/
  |---- .profile
  |---- etc...
```

In the `.profile` file add ...

```
export OCI_LIB_DIR=$HOME/oracle/instantclient
export OCI_INC_DIR=$HOME/oracle/instantclient/sdk/include
```

When you `cf push` your application, the Oracle Instant Client libraries and the `.profile` script will be pushed up with your application code. Prior to your application running, the `.profile` file will be sourced and those environment variables will be activated. These should help your application find the location of where the Oracle Instant Client resides, within your app directory.

But still I am getting above mentioned same issue... Please help here...

Comment: How are you uploading the OCI library files? Your app directory structure doesn't include "oracle", but maybe that's covered in "etc"? Also, have you verified where $HOME points? To what directory is the app deployed when you push it?